# How to minimize Thunderbird to tray in GNU/Linux/Debian?

Tags: debian, kde, thunderbird, tray

How can one minimize Thunderbird to the tray bar in Debian 10/KDE?

Using bintray didn't work when trying to install it (`sudo apt-get install birdtray`) I get:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 birdtray : Depends: thunderbird but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I'm looking for other ways to get this done than using the [Minimize On Close](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/minimize-on-close/) AddOn for Thunderbird because it requires the permission for "Have full, unrestricted access to Thunderbird, and your computer" and there might be other ways.

Various other AddOns don't run with the Thunderbird version that currently is in Debian's repos (78.11.0).

If there currently is no way to get this done, I'm also interested if there are any plans (issues) to build this functionality into Thunderbird so that it can be minimized to tray just like countless other apps that run on GNU/Linux.

Comment: it makes no sense to lie to your package manager and then subsequently complain that it isn't working correctly. If you want to install `birdtray` and have blocked installation of one of its dependencies, you'll have to install it the same way you installed thunderbird itself

Comment: I haven't blocked one of its dependencies and have installed Thunderbird from the Debian stable repos with it iirc and if the Apper installation history is correct. I would have put it in the question if I installed Thunderbird any other way.

Comment: Did you try SysTray-X after upgrade to Debian 11? The last [version](https://github.com/Ximi1970/systray-x/releases/tag/0.8.0) should support Thunderbird 91 properly. App looks pretty solid and does its job. It needs full access rights though, in order to overcome WebExtensions limitations. But I think it's pretty safe to use, for example Archlinux added it to its [repo](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/systray-x-git).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Birdtray worked after upgrading to Debian11.

Start it with `birdtray` then right-click on the tray icon->Settings->Hiding and check the following settings:

- Start Thunderbird when Birdtray starts
- Hide/show Thunderbird window when clicking on tray icon
- Hide Thunderbird window when it is minimized

To minimize Thunderbird to the tray *minimize* Thunderbird - looks like if you closed it via the X button you can't open it anymore by clicking the Birdtray/Thunderbird icon in the traybar.

You can then set up accounts to monitor in the Monitoring tab of the Birdtray settings.

[Systray-X simply didn't work](https://github.com/Ximi1970/systray-x/issues/86) for unknown reasons.

Edit: **[here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1627479)** is the Thunderbird code issue about this. This would be the proper solution, not the workaround.

Comment: Take into consideration that `birdtray` works in a hackish way. Package description says: _it suffers from problems like noticing new mails only after a delay, having to restart Thunderbird just to hide its window, etc._

Comment: Good to point that out, edited the question to add the code issue for a proper solution

Answer (score 2):

I use SysTray-X, works great.

https://github.com/Ximi1970/systray-x#binaries-system

Comment: I followed the guide for Debian10/KDE there and it doesn't work. What do I have to do after installing systray-x? I started Thunderbird and minimized it which minimizes it just like before and the X Close button just doesn't do anything anymore (it doesn't quit Thunderbird or minimize it to the tray or anything else).

Comment: are you using Wayland? the linked github page currently states that it doesn't work in a Wayland desktop

Comment: Sadly not: `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` returns X11.

Comment: Did you run /usr/bin/SysTray-X? It should be the in the tray when running, right click > preferences and set it up. I also see it in ~/.config/ksmserverrc as part of my saved session program7=/usr/bin/SysTray-X.

Comment: There isn't any systrayx in the tray even after running that.

Comment: Looking a bit closer I see there is also a Thunderbird extension. More info here https://kirelos.com/systray-x-is-a-thunderbird-68-tray-icon-with-unread-email-counter-and-close-minimize-to-tray/